# How to get rid off ejabberd number of chats limit

Tags: ejabberd

I need to make more than 20 muc chats in my ejabberd installation.

By default only limited number of chats can be active.

Are there any ways to get rid of this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your questions is about the number of chat room a given user can join, you should check option `max_user_conferences` in `mod_muc`. See ejabberd `mod_muc` documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#mod-muc

If your question is about the max number of resource a given user can connect to ejabberd, you can increase the `max_user_sessions` limit in your ejabberd ACLs configuration. This is explain in ejabberd documentation: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#limiting-opened-sessions-with-acl

Comment: Maybe max_user_conferences is what I need. If user wanted to join more than 10 active chats, 11 chats makes him exit from first one f.e.